# Sharepoint Online custom app distribution failed for co-worker, not for me

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, spfx, spfx-webparts, app-catalog

I've been developing and deploying a custom web part on our SPO tenant for a while. Today, my co-worker tried to deploy a new version of the app.

He successfully uploaded to the app to https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/apps/AppCatalog/Forms/AllItems.aspx, and pressed the "Deploy" button that popped up - just like I always do.

But in the right most column on mentioned site (which I believe in English is named something like "Error from application package") he got a "distribution failed" error message (and a correlation ID).

I have no idea how to debug this, as I wouldn't know even where to find any logs. As this procedure works for me, I suspect it has something to do with access rights or something.

Does anyone here have an idea why this is happening, and how we can fix it?

PS. I originally posted this over at Microsoft's tech community, but didn't get any responses so I'm re-posting it here.

Comment: Check if your co-worker has site collection administrator permissions on app catalog site.

Comment: Thanks, @GaneshSanap, he didn't have those permissions, so this was likely the issue. Haven't verified it yet though, but will do so soon.

Comment: Sure, let me know if it works for you after adding another user to site collection administrators.

Comment: It was a permission issue. Another co-worker fixed the issue, and I'm not quite sure exactly which permission setting he had to tweak though.

Comment: Great, I will summarize our conversation in a answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is SharePoint site permissions related issue.

Try granting below permissions to your co-worker & it should work for you:

1. Site collection Administrator permissions on app catalog site - [Manage site admins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-site-collection-administrators)
2. SharePoint tenant administrator - [Assign admin roles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/assign-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide)